# managedObjectContext in Other View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have finally managed to get core data working and beginning to understand it. So far I have just been playing in a window based app with core data enabled, playing inside the app delegate files.

But how can I access my managedObjectContext from outside the app delegate, for example if I had a UIView subclass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sharing NSManagedObjectContext and other service classes between iphone/ipad tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437033/sharing-nsmanagedobjectcontext-and-other-service-classes-between-iphone-ipad-tabs)

Comment: Also probably worth mentioning you should think twice before sharing a managedObjectContext with a UIView subclass. UIView are inherently views and should not be dealing directly with the data model. You probably want to pass the context reference to another view controller and then pass a reference of a specific managed object(s) to a view, but not the actual context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

To get rid of warnings, cast the delegate as your actual AppDelegate; for example,

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

EDIT:

After you change up any data, you'll need to save it. Here's the method I use:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

NSError *error;
if (![moc save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save current data in current method.");
}
```

Change up the log statement as you see fit.

Comment: Uh oh. After deeper testing, it seems having implemented this the data only sticks around while the application does. As soon as the application is quit and reopened the data is gone! Ideas?!

Comment: Turns out the data saving issue was due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326303/datepicker-stopping-coredata-work